# Will downloading Mountain Lion from Mac AppStore resume if I restarted/shut down the computer?

Tags: mac-appstore

I'm about to download OS X Mountain Lion from Mac AppStore, and I wanna know if downloading Mountain Lion will resume if I restarted/shut down the computer?!

Thanks...
Muhammad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is done automatically when shutting down, but you can manually pause downloads in the **purchases** tab:

[image]

The Mac App Store allows to pause and resume downloads.

Also see the Apple support documentation:
[Mac App Store: How to resume interrupted downloads](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4485)